# Angular how to get an array from the database and push an element into it

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I am using Firebase and what I have a 'dictionary' with words and every word has different definitions. I am trying to get the array with the definitions for a certain word from the backend and add the new definition to it.

This is what the data should look like:

```
words 
    'Word1'
        'Definitions'
            'Definition1'
            'Definition2'
    'Word2'
        'Definitions'
            'Definition1'
```

What I did is but I cannot get the property 'definitions' from the value changes:

```
let data = {
  name: word,
  definitions: [],
}

let newDefinition = 'Some definition'

let obj = this.db.object(`words/${word}`);

let obs = obj.valueChanges().subscribe(x => {
  changes = x;

  // If the word doesn't exist, create it.
  if (x === null) {
    data.definitions.push(this.newDefinition);
    obj.set({ definitions: data.definitions, word: data.word });

  // If the word exists add the definition to its list.
  } else {
    data.definitions = x.definitions;
    data.definitions.push(this.newDefinition);

    obj.update({ definitions: data.definitions });
  }
  obs.unsubscribe();
});
```

Comment: what's in `this.newDef`?

Comment: Its the new definition that I want to add, sorry I edited my code to be more understandable

Comment: So what is the problem/error you are having?

Comment: Well I get "error TS2339: Property 'definitions' does not exist on type '{}'.", because 'x' is an empty object at first and it hasn't recieved any data from firebase. I don't know how to get past this maybe there is a way to tell the program that it will recieve that property, but I don't know how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to cast the `x` to `any`:

```
data.definitions = (<any>x).definitions;
```

But for integrity you should use TypeScript interfaces to define a structure for the data you get from your database.

Comment: You mean something like this?

    `export interface Word {

       definitions: string[];

    }`

Comment: Oh and btw 
`data.definitions = (<any>x).definitions;` worked like a charm, thank you very much!